# Sql query to last records from table

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have sql table with following columns

```
CrewID
Lat
Lon
DateCreated
```

Now this table stores Latitude and Longitude of each crew when they travel, along with Datetime when the position is recorded.

I need to write a query which will give me the last recorded position of each crew from this table, based on `DateCreated`.

Comment: Every crew has multiple records in that table you need last record of each crew right?

Comment: Hullo, how about `max(DateCreated)` ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Add sample data, and the expected result (as formatted text). Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select top 1 * from table_name order by DateCreated desc
```

**desc** will return the latest date and **asc** will return the oldest date present in your table , the above query will work for SQL_Server , you can use **Limit** keyword for mysql in the same way .

**Explanation**

1. Order the record according to the date
2. Select the top 1 from the arranged data  (Last recorded data row)
3. You can write column names instead of * to filter the data

**Learning Resource** : [This](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)

Comment: I think This will return only one value not by every CrewId.

Comment: yes , it will return one value , as question was "I need to write a query which will give me the last recorded position of each crew from this table, "

Comment: Suppose you have ten Crew id then what result your query will return??

Comment: Latest crew , or oldest crew depends on ordering , for further guidance you can refer to the given link

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tn.*
FROM table_name tn
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name tnb
    ON tn.CrewID = tnb.CrewID AND tn.DateCreated< tnb.DateCreated
WHERE tnb.CrewID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out This

```
SELECT CrewID,max(Lat),Max(Lon),Max(DateCreated)
 Group By CrewID
```

Please reply